# Loading images from url to picturebox in .net

Tags: .net, picturebox, imageurl

I am trying to pull an image from website using an url. It's a company website only accessible from the companys' network and has profile for all the members including their pictures(they are allowed to upload new pictures), and also has some avatar images for few profiles. 
I am able to extract the avatar images, the logos or the other graphical files in the website but can't get the pictures that were uploaded by the user.

**'this works fine**

```
PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://....../images/icons/profilepics/Avatar-10.png"
```

**'this doesn't work, always shows me the error image**

```
PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://....../download/attachments/..../user1543.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't give like that, since its configured with web server. try to use like below. 
If you want to use the download path, first try to access the image through your web browser, i don't think you will be, because of security thread.

```
picture.ImageLocation = Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "Resources\Images\1.jpg");
```

Comment: I can access the pictures from my browser, and its not only that web page I can't access any pictures from any web page. And your code suggests me to keep the image files in the local location which is not possible as it (.net) doesn't load anything.